# MSSQL: Initial database

Tags: sql-server, docker

Is there a way to start an MSSQL server in Docker with an initially created database? I like to avoid to mount entrypoint scripts.

For instance, in PostgresSQL, one simply can start the server with environmental variable `POSTGRES_DB=mydb` in order to have database named `mydb` automatically created. I am looking for an equivalent option for MSSQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, MSSQL doesn't have a feature like that. You have to create the database yourself.

Comment: You could just run a script internally and run `CREATE DATABASE mydb`

Comment: @HansKilian Actually it does, it's called `User Instance` but it's deprecated and not recommended. Really just run `IF NOT EXISTS... CREATE DATABASE...`